# Utilizing Import-Csv based on user input to pull json blob from website

Tags: json, powershell, if-statement, foreach, invoke-webrequest

Scenario:

User has csv with hostnames or one or two hostnames.
User needs to answer multiple options such as "Do you have CSV or Just a Hostname?" and then depending on the answer more input such as "Please enter a file path for CSV" or "Enter a hostname"

After which I need to use if statements and for each loops to pull the json data from a website.
Lastly I need to out-file that data and validate with convertfrom-json.

I have a good Function built called "Get-UserInput. I am stuck on how to pass that input through to scrape the hosts for the json data. Any help is much appreciated as this is my first more complex powershell script.

Comment: You should include the bit of your code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to figure this out today on my own. I dumped the function and figured out if and elsif statements and I got it to work!

Comment: Now I just need to out-file from each host to multiple .txt files. .